# PDF Box Detecting font list not embedded and XFA Form

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, xfa

Good morning

We are evaluating PDFBox for detecting some information about PDF

We would like to know if it's possbile to detect:

1) Which fonts are embedded and which not

2) XFA form inside the PDF

Thanks and Regards

Comment: How you checked the docs?

Comment: i woulld like to use the API , but i don't know how to use

Comment: That's what the docs are for, no? Read the docs, search the web (here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392432/how-to-check-fully-embedded-and-subset-embedded-font-using-pdfbox). Then come back and ask help on the parts that do not work. That's what developers do.

Comment: @user3526455 I completely agree with Matt and David. To give your search in the docs a sense of direction, though: As far as I know PDFBox does not offer the functionality you look for as high-level API calls (e.g. there is no `document.getFonts().getEmbedded()`) but PDFBox allows you to access the PDF structure in a more low-level API, and this API indeed allows you to check for embeddedness of fonts and presence of xfa.